# Universal selector in Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm trying to convert from sass to SC but I cannot seem to find what I would use to replace the the universal selector (*). The specific block of code that's giving me trouble:

```
*, *::after, *::before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've gathered from reading docs and similar questions here that I should replace ::after and ::before with :last-child and :first-child but would I replace that element selector? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you trying to use this selector? We use this very selector in our app without issue. What is the "trouble"?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I'll clarify! I'm using Styled Components and was asking how I would go about initializing the universal selector as a component instead of how its done in regular CSS

Comment: CSS selectors aren't components though. Styled-components allows you to write using standard CSS selectors, so `*` works the same. I'm still asking what the issue is. Perhaps you should include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example to provide a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Ampersands (&) are your best friend when using styled components. Here is what the styled-component documentation says:

Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting
The preprocessor we use, stylis, supports scss-like syntax for automatically nesting styles.

The ampersand (&) can be used to refer back to the main component. Here are some more examples of its potential usage:

```
const Thing = styled.div.attrs((/* props */) => ({ tabIndex: 0 }))`
  color: blue;

  &:hover {
    color: red; // <Thing> when hovered
  }

  & ~ & {
    background: tomato; // <Thing> as a sibling of <Thing>, but maybe not directly next to it
  }

  & + & {
    background: lime; // <Thing> next to <Thing>
  }

  &.something {
    background: orange; // <Thing> tagged with an additional CSS class ".something"
  }

  .something-else & {
    border: 1px solid; // <Thing> inside another element labeled ".something-else"
  }
`

render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Thing>Hello world!</Thing>
    <Thing>How ya doing?</Thing>
    <Thing className="something">The sun is shining...</Thing>
    <div>Pretty nice day today.</div>
    <Thing>Don't you think?</Thing>
    <div className="something-else">
      <Thing>Splendid.</Thing>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

If you put selectors in without the ampersand, they will refer to children of the component.

```
const Thing = styled.div`
  color: blue;

  .something {
    border: 1px solid; // an element labeled ".something" inside <Thing>
    display: block;
  }
`

render(
  <Thing>
    <label htmlFor="foo-button" className="something">Mystery button</label>
    <button id="foo-button">What do I do?</button>
  </Thing>
)
```

Finally, the ampersand can be used to increase the specificity of rules on the component; this can be useful if you are dealing with a mixed styled-components and vanilla CSS environment where there might be conflicting styles:

```
const Thing = styled.div`
  && {
    color: blue;
  }
`

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  div${Thing} {
    color: red;
  }
`

render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Thing>
      I'm blue, da ba dee da ba daa
    </Thing>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

[styled-components: Basics](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#coming-from-css)

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to reply, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
export const UniversalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
*,*::after, *::before{
box-sizing: border-box;
}`;
```

now, import "UniversalStyle" in your App.jsx.

```
import { UniversalStyle } from './AppStyle';
function App() {
return (
    <div>
        <UniversalStyle />
    </div>
)
}
```